# Custom Fields in Virtuemart allowing user to enter amounts

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, custom-fields

my question is probably simple for most but its troubling me and ive been googling for sometime now.

Im trying to create a product on this following website for a client

https://www.anigmabeauty.co.nz/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id=1&Itemid=235

I want to create another Voucher called $100+ Gift Voucher with that voucher set at $100.00 obviously. when the viewer clicks on this I want to have a "Enter Amount" box where the viewer can enter the amount they want to pay for a Gift Voucher. for example if they wanted a $210.00 Gift Voucher, they simply enter $210.00

I managed to do this with custom fields but it then adds the amount entered (eg. $210.00) onto the $100.00 which I dont want. If it is possible I would like the $100+ Gift Voucher set to $0 dollars and whenever the viewer types in the value they want (eg. $210.00) and then go to the Shopping Cart the Total amount will be $210.00

Any help would be AMAZING

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't exactly do this with current VM without any core files modification especially cart helper and related files.

But i think you can achieve this in another way .like  you are planning to provide a text box for entering the amount in front end . instead of that you can provide a list box with predefined values.This you can achieve by using the VM custom fields options .
There is one option for making a list of values for custom fields.

Hope this may help you..

Comment: Thanks Jobin, Ive tried to make a dropdown menu but say if I have the price set to $100 dollars and they select a price of $110 from the dropdown instead of adding the $10 dollars onto the original $100 price it adds $110.

Any ideas on how to stop this? tutorials?